Why the Grid Layout Group is not working with the Constraint > Fixed Column Count?
image screenshot of the canvas settings

and this image screenshot of the image child with the Grid Layout Group.
the image Rect Transform is set to stretch.

then i duplicated the child images 10 times but on the top two lines the images on the right are "getting out" from inside on the right side.
i thought the Grid Layout Group should fix that automatically and make the images to fit the image parent no matter what number of Constraint Count i set and the space between them and the size.

Not exactly, no .. the grid constraints it according to your settings which is a width of 10 columns .. which is exactly what you are getting as result .. quite inconvenient tbh .. when I did this I ended up having a component calculating the constraints and cell size dynamically so that it looked nice regardless of how the rect was scaled ... but there seems nothing built in for this ..
